# Get Typescript type as value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have components like these

```js
type TestComponentProps = {
  title: string;
}

const TestComponent: React.FC<TestComponentProps> = ({
  title,
}) => {
  return <div>TestComponent: {title}</div>;
};

type TestComponent2Props = {
  body: string;
}

const TestComponent2: React.FC<TestComponent2Props> = ({ body }) => {
  return <div>TestComponent2: {body}</div>;
};
```

I would need an interface that would allow me to configure which component to render and get the props of that particular component

```
const dataToRender:Array<{
   component: TestComponent | TestComponent2,
   data: propsOf<component>
}> = [
   {
      component: TestComponent,
      data: { title: '123' }
   },
   {
      component: TestComponent2,
      data: { body: 'lorem ipsum' }
   }
];
```

Ideally I'd need to get the props of the particular component in a way "I want to render this component and I can only accept the correct props based on the props of that component"

Comment: I think you want an array of props only - not components - and the type of that array's elements would be `TestComponent2Props | TestComponentProps`. Then, write a [type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html) to determine which type of props a given value is, by looking at the existence of `body` vs. `title`. Then Use that type guard to selectively map those props to components by instantiating a new component with the given props. Question is pretty unclear though, so I can only guess that's what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, but not with plain typesciprt type annotations. In `vue js` for particular, for better typing you need to use `defineComponent` wrapper, that just return it argument (`id`) but with types.

In you case you can use this function.

```js
function defineComponent<TProps, TModal extends React.ComponentType<TProps>>(x: {
  component: TModal & React.ComponentType<TProps>
  data: TProps
}) {
  return x
}
```

And use it like so:

```js
const dataToRender = [
  defineComponent({
    component: TestComponent,
    data: { title: "123" },
  }),
  defineComponent({
    component: TestComponent2,
    data: { title: "lorem ipsum" }, // error here
  }),
] as const
```